# React router dom not showing a component in the webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The Layout page is not showing up if the home page does and vice versa i tried changing the version of the react router dom to 5 but it is still not working I also used router insted of route it is still not working.

```
//App.js file
import React from "react";
import { Route,Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';
import './App.scss';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <>
      <Route exact path='/' Component={Layout} />
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      </>
    </Routes>
  );
  }

export default App;
```

i also tried restarting the application and i also tried deleteing and reinstalling the react-router-dom and node_modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paths you specified for both routes are the same.
Use a different route for one component.
And also if you are using react-router-dom version 6, pass component to element prop.

```html
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

// Import your components (Layout and Home) here

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
       <Route exact path="/layout" element={<Layout />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: '<Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Layout />} />
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>' i changed it but still it is showing only the home page